# How to add lookup to Count inside an annotate

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, annotations

I want to get the count of all lectures with status=1. Currently I can only get the count of all lectures using the following line of code:

```
 topic = Topic.objects.annotate(lectures_count=Count('lectures')).get(id=topic_id)
```

Here are my models

```
class Lecture(models.Model):
    id = HashidAutoField(primary_key=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lectures')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=1)


class Topic(models.Model):
        id = HashidAutoField(primary_key=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
        status = models.BooleanField(default=1)
```

Comment: Lecture.objects.filter(status=1).count()

Comment: Author needs to get `Lecture` count with `status = 1` for particular `Topic` inside `annotate`

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When, IntegerField,

 Topic.objects.annotate(
     lecs_with_status_1=Count(
         Case(
             When(
                 lectures__status=1,
                 then=1
             ),
             output_field=IntegerField()
         )
     ).values('id', 'lecs_with_status_1')
```

As a result you will get Topics with count of lectures with 1 status.

Comment: Thank you for this, but i realized that if i chain the annotates i get very inaccurate results. topic = BatchTopic.objects.annotate(
        lectures_count=Count(Case(When(lectures__status=1, then=1)), output_field=IntegerField())
    ).annotate(
        references_count=Count(Case(When(references__status=1, then=1)), output_field=IntegerField())
    ).get(id=topic_id)